# how to apply a custom css class on a magento 2 customer forget password page

Tags: magento2

i want to apply some css for a customer forget password page only like for title. if i apply any css then it reflects on all pages but i want to apply only on a single page. can some one guide pls?
I am using m2.3.5p1
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to look at the `<body>` of the specific page you want to modify. Every page's `<body>` has a unique class you can root your css selector to.

In case of the forgot password page, the body's class is `customer-account-forgotpassword`. So, in case of the page title, just add

```
body.customer-account-forgotpassword h1{
//yourstyle
}
```

to your _extend.less or wherever you manage your css.

Comment: Always happy to help:). Please accept my answer if it solves your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers